# How are the landing, takeoff, and cruise speeds calculated for my homebuilt ultralight?

Tags: performance-calculation, ultralight, homebuilt

How can I calculate the takeoff, landing, and cruise speeds of my ultralight with a total weight (with load) of 120 kg, average air density of 1.23 kg/m3, wing area of 13.18 m2, and a coefficient of lift 1.15?

Comment: Do you have a Pilot's Operating Handbook (POH) for the plane? There should be charts in it to help you determine speeds.

Comment: @CrossRoads Judging by [OP's previous activity on the site](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/30253/david-teahay?tab=questions) (as well as the description in [their profile](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/30253/david-teahay?tab=profile)), they are building their own airplane. So no, there is almost certainly no POH, or any other data for that matter beyond what OP has been able to determine on their own.

Comment: @CrossRoads please post answers in the answer field, not in the comments.

Comment: Question should deleted, OP has another post with same question where it is further noted he is building a plane from scratch with data, such as POH, available.

Comment: @CrossRoads I see no such post. Please link.

Comment: I have no answer. OP is building his own plane per his profile "I am currently working on a homebuilt ultralight" and see his other questions regarding 1 vs 2 engines, moving the control surfaces, etc.  There is no POH for looking up speeds such as might be found in a kit from a manufacturer.

Comment: For constant weight, lift coefficient and air density, the resulting speed will be constant, too...

Comment: Please add whether you have a flap mechanism or not. And your CLmax value with the flap setting(s) is important.

Comment: No flap mechanism @Gurkan